# Which branch is behind the tag?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I'm in a cloned source-tree created by using a *tag*. How do I determine, which *branch* is it, that the tagging was applied to -- so that I can pull in newer commits made into that branch?

The `git branch` command simply gives the name of the tag:

```
* (detached from the_tag_name)
  master
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the tree is not too messy you can visually inspect it: `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is, how I solved this for now -- but, I'm sure, there is a better way:

```
% git branch -v
* (detached from the_tag_name) HASH1 Commit-message1
  master                       HASH2 Commit-message2
```

I then followed up with:

```
% git branch -r --contains HASH1
```

The above command lists all branches, local and remote (thanks to the `-r`), that have the particular commit in them. In my case, there was only one such branch...

Hoping for a better solution from git gurus...

Comment: There is not necessarily *any* branch associated with a tag. You can tag a commit, then *delete the branch*, if you like. Someone might do this to indicate that there's no further development to be done here. But you might get many branch names from a `git branch -r --contains <tag>` result, and that leaves you in more or less the same position. There's no substitute for actual documentation, if present; documentation can describe intent, while Git labels can't.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I determine, which branch is it, that the tagging was applied to...

You can't, at least not for sure, and by using Git alone. As you already know, you can see what branches contain the tag(ged commit) *right now*, but this sort of history isn't stored in a clone. Note there is no requirement that a tag be on any branch at all! It could be otherwise orphaned, but will still show up in a clone.

There are some possibilities that might get you close:

1. If the tag is so new that it hasn't shown up on other branches yet, then looking right now may reveal which branch it's on. If you set up a continuous fetch monitor you may be able to isolate the branch the tag shows up with, which would be a good (but not perfect) indicator of the branch it was created on.
2. Some tools maintain a push history. This would be similar to a built-in monitor described in #1.
3. If you have access to the computer that created the tag, you may be able to search the reflog on that machine to see what branch the repo had checked out at the time the tag was created.

Comment: Tag is not just a commit, though -- a commit might be present in multiple branches, but a tag identifies all files, uniquely. A tag is a snapshot of some branch, is not it? Which branch is it, is my question...

Comment: @MikhailT. "A tag is a snapshot of some branch, is not it?" It is not. "but a tag identifies all files, uniquely." Actually, that's what a commit does; a commit is a snapshot of all of your files at the time the commit was made. A commit does not contain any information about a branch, unless you bake the branch name into the commit message, e.g. "Merge branch some-branch-name into main". A branch is simply a pointer to a commit, and so is a tag, except that tags may be annotated too. I suppose you could store a branch name in the tag annotation if you really want to.

Comment: @MikhailT. here's some more information about [tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). Perhaps more importantly, I would also recommend reading about [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell#ch03-git-branching) which I suspect will clear up a misunderstanding that motivated you to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: the same commit can be merged into multiple branches, which can still differ from each other in other aspects. Therefore a commit cannot identify _all_ files, can it?

Comment: @MikhailT note if you tag a commit, then both that tag and commit will be present "on" multiple branches as well. (Really that means reachable rather than "on".) The only reason branches might differ from each other is if they point to different commits. When branches both point to the same commit there is no difference between them, except for their name.